# trying to use a react admin template + strapi + electron

Tags: node.js, webpack, strapi

I'm trying to build a project using:

- Strapi framework http://strapi.io
- ElectronJS http://electron.atom.io
- React template http://coreui.io

My objective is to have an Electron packaged app with strapi server inside it serving this react free template.

So I'm totally confused about putting these tools together. Each one has your webpackage, dev server, build process, etc...

I know there's no easy recipe for this, but is there any way or tip to help me on this, or just a direction?

Comment: I'm one of the creators of [Strapi](http://strapi.io). The framework is dedicated to building powerful APIs and Node.js backend. From what I understand of your project, you will have two projects.

1 - Front-end: a React app for templating your views, wrapped into an Electron app to be able to use it as a native desktop app.
2 - Backend: a Strapi app hosted on AWS, DO, Heroku, etc. to distribute the data.

IMO, the backend shouldn't be a part of the Electron app.

Comment: I'm going this way as you said, but still a pain. Thank you!

Comment: Hello @anderlaini did you able to progress? On top of this idea would be pipeline to gatsby build.

Comment: @tunaayberk no I've change from react to ionic. its pretty easier form starting on mobile development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did that, it is possible to do, but i still have somethings not figured-out like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63292789/electron-with-strapi-cannot-find-module-package-json)

So to achieve your objective this needs to be in your electron index.js file,
You need to build the front-end, and paste the output from the build process into your public folder of strapi.

Also you need to copy package.json with (api, assets, build, config, db, extensions, public) folders from your strapi project into the packaged electron app folder (beside the exe file).

I know it is old question but i thought it might help someone.

```
function createWindow() {

    // Create the browser window.
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        maximizable: true,
        title: "Dental System",
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })
    win.maximize();

    strapi().start().then(() => {
        win.loadURL('http://localhost:1337/');
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });

    win.on('closed', () => {
        app.quit();
    })
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow()
    }
})
```