# Electron with strapi, Cannot find module package.json

Tags: node.js, electron, package.json, strapi

I built an application using [strapi](https://strapi.io/), i am trying to package it inside electron using electron-builder.

The packaging is done well, but when i start the app, it shows this message

```
PS E:\Development\DentalSystem\dentalBE_test\dist\win-unpacked>
(node:13196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'E:\Development\DentalSystem\dentalBE_test\dist\win-unpacked\package.json'
Require stack:
- E:\Development\DentalSystem\dentalBE_test\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app\node_modules\strapi\lib\Strapi.js
- E:\Development\DentalSystem\dentalBE_test\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app\node_modules\strapi\lib\index.js
- E:\Development\DentalSystem\dentalBE_test\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app\index.js
-
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:17)
    at Function.o._resolveFilename (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:281:679)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:769:28)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at new Strapi (E:\Development\DentalSystem\dentalBE_test\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app\node_modules\strapi\lib\Strapi.js:94:21)
    at module.exports (E:\Development\DentalSystem\dentalBE_test\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app\node_modules\strapi\lib\Strapi.js:564:18)
    at createWindow (E:\Development\DentalSystem\dentalBE_test\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app\index.js:23:5)
(node:13196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13196) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

What seems to be the problem is that my application is looking to package.json file inside the root folder (directly relative to the exe file), while it exist inside the (app) folder with all other resources of the system.

this is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "DentalSys",
  "main": "./index.js",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "description": "Dental Clinic Management System",
  "productName": "DentalSys",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.kldoon.dentalSys",
    "asar": false    
  },
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "strapi-start": "strapi start",
    "strapi-prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm start",
    "strapi-build": "strapi build",
    .....
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
    "electron": "^9.1.2",
    "electron-builder": "^22.4.1",
    ......
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "knex": "0.20.13",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.1.1",
    "strapi": "3.0.0-beta.17.5",
    .......
}
```

And this is my electron (index.js) file

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, dialog } = require('electron')
const path = require("path");

const strapi = require('strapi');
//const { exec } = require("child_process");

function createWindow() {

    // Create the browser window.
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        maximizable: true,
        title: "Dental System",
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })
    win.maximize();

    strapi().start().then(() => {
        win.loadURL('http://localhost:49862/');
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });

    win.on('closed', () => {
        app.quit();
    })
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow()
    }
})
```

I tried multiple solutions but none work, i hope someone can help with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi @Khaldoun Khaled, thanks for this. I managed to run and package an electron app with your codes example. But i have two issues thought, maybe you can have some tips how to address it. First, is it possible to run strapi autoReload on electron. Second, i try too use asar setup on package.json, but i found an error when i run the binary, currently i only try building into AppImage format. The error is when strapi loading local plugins, i dont really know what happen, but i guess is it having trouble reading it, propably because how strapi read them.

Comment: feels like i have to do unpack asar on it, but i dont know how to resolve it after i unpack it. Do you have any idea ?.
It run ok with asar set to false thought, just like your example, but i think i give a try first how to setup it using asar.

Comment: as a references, here is the boilerplate code i put on github, https://github.com/afdallismen/electron-strapi-boilerplate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be easy fix, with dir option of strapi constructor

```
strapi({
dir: __dirname + '/'     ///<==== add this 
}).start().then(() => {
  win.loadURL('http://localhost:1337/');
}).catch((e) => {
  dialog.showMessageBox(win, { message: JSON.stringify(e) });
  console.log(e);
});
```